# Why does my java TimerTask stop executing in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am running a java application in a TimerTask using the schedule method, i.e. it runs at certain intervals and if the timertask gets delayed it does not try to play catch-up. I want the program to run for as long as possible if not indefinitely. I am using Netbeans 7.3.

However, I find that after a few hours (sometimes only 1 hour and sometimes over 24 hours) the program stops printing to the console and in fact stops running altogether. I know it isn't simply that it stops printing to the console because the program also sends an email regularly, and after it stops the emails stop coming as well. It does not always say "build complete" or throw an exception, though sometimes it will simply say "build complete" and stop running.

I have tried looking around the web, but I cannot seem to find any conclusive answer. I saw somewhere that the TimerTask will stop running if it throws an unchecked excpetion, but since it does not always stop at the end of a TimerTask but rather at some random point in the middle of a task, I don't think that is what's happening.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong and how I can work around it?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Paul

EDIT: after I tried putting a logger into my timertask, the code errored out with the following exception:
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for Logging.txt. This may very well be a separate problem because I have never used a logger.  I read somewhere that this exception probably means I am missing some permissions to write to the file in java (not sure if that is the case or how to fix in Netbeans). If I fix the logger it and it's unrelated I will delete this edit

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the Broadcast function involves a lot of communication with various servers. I think the problem might be that the program simply gets stuck on a line and never completes. In this case I need to figure out a way to have the broadcast method timeout after a certain amount of time and try again.

EDIT: here is an example of my code:

```
    public void RUN(){
                exchanges.add(Bitstamp);
                exchanges.add(BTCE);
                exchanges.add(CampBX);
    t.schedule(
    new TimerTask()
         {
        public void run()
         {
     Broadcast(exchanges);


    UseLogger.Log();
         }
}, 0,15000);

}

public static void Broadcast(ArrayList<Exchange> exchanges){
 for (int i=0; i<exchanges.size();i++){
       exchanges.get(i).prepareGetUpdate();
   }
        System.out.println("************** TICKERS *****************");
        try{
    for (int i=0; i<exchanges.size();i++){
        System.out.println(exchanges.get(i).getPrices());
    }
        tickerException=false;
        } catch (Exception e){
        tickerException=true;
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("************** BALANCES *****************");
    try{
    for (int i=0;i<exchanges.size();i++){
        System.out.println("i: " + i);
        System.out.println(exchanges.get(i).getBalance());

    }
    balanceException=false;
    } catch (Exception e){
        balanceException=true;
    }
      System.out.println("************ ORDERS *****************");
    try{
    for (int i=0; i< exchanges.size();i++){
       exchanges.get(i).getOrders(); 
       if (exchanges.get(i).exchangeName.contentEquals("BTCE")){
           exchanges.get(i).Total_btc+=exchanges.get(i).btcInOrders;
           exchanges.get(i).Total_usd+=exchanges.get(i).usdInOrders;
       }
    }
    orderException=false;
    } catch (Exception e){
        orderException = true;
    }

    for (int i=0; i< exchanges.size();i++){
       exchanges.get(i).getUpdate(); 
    } 



    btcDiff = totalBTC-originalTotal;
    btcNeutral=true;
}
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging. I think a some aggressive logging will go a long way to helping you. Otherwise, I'm not sure how folks who cannot see your code or experience your problem can help.

Comment: @Hovercraft full of Eels, thanks for your response. I posted an example of my code. I normally just print the error message whenever an exception is thrown. But I suspect you mean using an actual logging api. I have never use done before, but tried reading up on java.util.logger and adding it to my timertask, but I can't seem to get any useful output.

Comment: use System.out.println() for the time being. It sounds like you're running in a development environment, so it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @iajrz, I made sure I am catching any exceptions and printing out their messages every time, but I do not see any error messages printed before the program stops. Does this mean there is an unchecked exception? If so, how do I print one of those?

Comment: Be careful not to call `TimerTask.randomlyStop(true);` This has tripped me up a number of times.

Comment: @Dave, do you think you are witty? I hope so because you are certainly not helpful

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, I just don't appreciate being taunted. I understand this may seem like an easy problem to some but I have been programming for only a year, and up until now I have been able to always print out exceptions and look at error messages in order to debug. But in this case the error does not always happen in the same place within the timertask, so it seems that it has something to do with the scheduler itself. Obviously it isn't "random", but it is unpredictable in the sense I just described and that is why I think it is not a trivial case of debugging with print statements.